# MobX - Retrieve index of observable array object?

Tags: javascript, mobx

When narrowing down a selection to a single object in an observable array, how can I get that object's index efficiently?

```
@observable questionsList = [{
  id: 1,
  question: "Is the earth flats?",
  answer: "Some long answer here..."
}, {
  id: 2,
  question: "Does the moon have life?",
  answer: "Some long answer here..."
}];

const quesitonId = 2; 
const question = this.questionsList.find(q => q.id === questionId);
const questionIndex = // should be 1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the [**findIndex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
questionsList.findIndex(q => q.id === 2);
```

```js
var questionsList = [{
  id: 1,
  question: "Is the earth flats?",
  answer: "Some long answer here..."
}, {
  id: 2,
  question: "Does the moon have life?",
  answer: "Some long answer here..."
}];

console.log(questionsList.findIndex(q => q.id === 2));
```

Comment: Thank you Tholle. Works great!

Comment: @Wonka Sweet :) Happy to help.

Comment: Interestingly this is not working on my Samsung S6 browser. On mobile chrome, firefox etc. no problem, but on the internal browser it throws an error stating findIndex is not a function on an observable array. Probably a bug, right?

Comment: @jkettmann That's odd. Might be a bug, but if you are not transpiling your code the arrow function might not work. Try `questionsList.findIndex(function (q) { return q.id === 2; });`

Comment: No, that's not working. The observable array doesn't seem to have a method findIndex on this one browser. I'll file a bug report

Comment: Got it. I was just not aware, that this is a es6 feature. Using findIndex from lodash solved my problem

Comment: You need to transpile AND use the babel polyfills to be able to use it!